# unable to access returned values of global class method

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, rest-service, restresource

I am trying to access the returned values of a global class method and store them in a string. The string is declared as global static string. The value gets stored in the string when in the method. But when I try use the string in other method of same class, the string is blank/null. There are no values in it.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/xyz/cases/V1/')
global with sharing class controllerc
    { 
      global static string sentresponse;
      @HttpPost   
      global static Casewrapper createNewCase() 
     {
       Casewrapper response= new Casewrapper ();
       ....
       ....
       sentresponse=string.valueOf(response);
       system.debug('^^Sentreposne'+sentresponse); // here the string has returned values.
       return response;
     }
  global static void ErrorMesage()
  {
    Attachment attachres=new Attachment();
    ..... 
    system.debug('++response' + sentresponse); // here the string is null
    attachres.Body=Blob.valueOf(sentreponse);
    ......
    insert attachres;
  }
}
```

Please help in how to fetch the response and call it in other method of the same class and assign it to the body of attachment. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sfdcdev

Comment: Static can't store Values , each transaction in Sales-force starts as a fresh slate, with nothing loaded in memory.

Comment: Or Another Alternative way is keep in server Cache. Way of doing this would be to use the Platform Cache to store the data serverside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Nitesh's comment, a call to `createNewCase` and a call to `ErrorMesage` are independent. This allows a request to be processed by any server and so greatly helps scalability and simplifies failover. Every requests is starting from scratch as far as the state in code variables (including `static` ones) is concerned.

So your choices are:

- Perform both operations in a single method
- Return the value required by the second method as part of the results of the first method and then pass the value back as an argument to the second method

Comment: I am not so sure about this , can we use salesforce platform cache in rest Api?

Comment: @NITHESHK Perhaps, but that would be a complicated solution to a problem that could be solved more simply.

Comment: Hi KeithC  and Nithesh .Thanks for the reply. As Keith said, I tried to return the response by saving it in a string and passing that string as a parameter in the method call. Still the value is null.

Comment: Just FYI, I am calling the ErrorMesage() method in catch block of  createNewCase() method itself.   But as you guys said, static cannot store values, what would be the best approach that can be used here to store and use the method's returned  value in other method.

Comment: Performed both the operations in Single method.